# Angular Material Tab active link to put drop down arrow

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm beginner for the Angular & i try to do some Angular tab active line bar to replace some arrow but it's not working , anyone know how to do that correctly

[stackblitz sample here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btsem1)

**code**

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**css**

```
/* active tab */
::ng-deep .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label-active {
  color:#0f2241;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

/* ink bar */
::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar {
  background-color:red !important; background:  url('../../../assets/sg-img/drop-down-arrow.png');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `::ng-deep` set the ViewEncapsulation of your component to none:

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tab-group-stretched-example',
  templateUrl: 'tab-group-stretched-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab-group-stretched-example.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TabGroupStretchedExample {}
```

Then use the following CSS (I had to use another arrow since you used a local reference in your stackblitz):

```
.example-stretched-tabs {
  max-width: 800px;
}
/* active tab */
.mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label-active {
  color:#0f2241;
  background-color: lightblue;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* ink bar */
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
  background: none;
  content: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/60/60995.svg');
  height: 10px;
}
```

Is this what you were looking for: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btsem1-h4feok)?